# Is there a reason for unprotecting a question?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

I read about protected questions and I understand it, but is there a reason for **unprotecting** a question after it was marked as protected?

All I can think is that the question lost interest and will be ignored by newbies, but I'm not sure this is the reason for unprotecting.

I didn't find much information on unprotecting questions which is available for 15K users.

Comment: Maybe if it shouldn't have been protected in the first place?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier so it's for rollbacking an error? It can be done using moderator, no?

Comment: Probably, but why make moderator have to do it if the community can? Also, a protected question probably have some er... "protection" from normal closure flow. Unprotecting it allows for normal moderation from community? Just throwing ideas here, I can't even protec ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When to unprotect a question (from the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/377968)):

> Do unprotect questions that aren’t currently attracting a lot of attention and don’t have a long history of unproductive answers.

A question is protected to keep away low quality answers and comments (and even spam). This typically occurs while the question is new and gets many views (especially HNQ questions). According to the respective [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/08/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/), protection is

> meant to be a *reaction* to persistent abuse from anonymous or unproven participants: when a page attracts a lot of noise or vandalism from outside the community, Protecting it reduces the amount of clean-up needed later on.

But once the hype died down, you can unprotect it to allow low-reputation users, who actually want to contribute something useful, to answer it again. It's then also more likely that low-rep user found it, because they were specifically looking for it, not just because the link gets shared everywhere.

What is responsible for a "long history of unproductive answers" can probably only be determined on a case by case basis, but may include important on topic question that will constantly attract attention, like the highest voted questions on SO. Here's an interesting [Moderator note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely#comment37300870_2003505) to the question with the 3rd highest score:

> **Moderator note: If you intend to answer this question, do note that there are already 40 answers posted. Will your new answer add any substantial value?**

It's decisive to whom it has ceased to be interesting - to those who will post just a link (maybe even spam) or a "funny" comment, or those with an actual interest in the topic. The latter can be established users, but also someone who comes here for the first time.

After all, the (formerly) protected question may not have gotten a sufficient answer and keeping the bar for answers as low as possible is one of the goals of SE. So protection is only an emergency measure to be lifted, once the emergency is over.

The [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/08/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/) concludes about protection:

> Judicious use of this feature is critical to allowing these sites to handle large amounts of external attention, but *over-using* it breaks the system: Stack Exchange sites depend on a constant influx of new blood, both to answer new questions and provide updated information on old ones. When in doubt, err on the side of letting new users prove themselves before locking them out.

Comment: Chicken-and-egg proposition, it might well not have a long history *because* it was protected :)

Comment: We may want auto unprotect a question after a period of time.